Azure trusted signing Identity validation process stuck due to inability to upload required documents
I'm trying to create an identity to setup azure trusted signing. The process is stuck with "Action Required" status and is asking to "Provide additional documents to complete your validation request". Whenever I try to upload the document, it fails with the message: "Failed to uploaded documents. An error occured while uploading documents.:". Is there any way to fix this issue? I tried deleting and re-recreating the identity, but it did not work.

Ensure that the documents you are trying to upload meet the file size requirements mentioned in the documentation request email. and If it is not possible to provide additional documentation, update your account information to match any legal documents already provided or your official Company registration details.

If you are still unable to upload the required documents, you can contact Azure support by creating a support ticket in the Azure portal

The issue is finally resolved. It turned out to be missing "Trusted Signing Identity Verifier" role assignment, even though I had an owner role.
